# IOS objective-C loop through 2 arrays

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I've never done Objective-C before, only c and c++ a little. I made a small c++ program for fun, not the most efficient code but it didn't matter, it converts a word/sentence to a word/sentence with all the consonants adding op at the end.

```
char vowels[]{'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','q','w','x','y','z'};
string word;
int temp;


cout << "Enter a word or exit to stop program: " << endl;

getline(cin,word);

cout << "OP translation is: ";


for(int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++){

    if(word[i] == vowels[0] || word[i] == vowels[1] || word[i] == vowels[2] || word[i] == vowels[3] || word[i] == vowels[4] || word[i] == vowels[5] || word[i] == vowels[6]
       || word[i] == vowels[7] || word[i] == vowels[8] || word[i] == vowels[9] || word[i] == vowels[10] || word[i] == vowels[11] || word[i] == vowels[12] || word[i] == vowels[13]
       || word[i] == vowels[14] || word[i] == vowels[15] || word[i] == vowels[16] || word[i] == vowels[17] || word[i] == vowels[18] || word[i] == vowels[19] || word[i] == vowels[20]
       || word[i] == vowels[21]){
        if(word[0])
            cout<<word[i] << "op" << " ";
        else
            cout << " " << word[i] << "op";
    }
    else
        cout<<word[i] << " ";
}
```

Now I want to try to make it into an app but I'm not really sure how to loop through the string and array in objective-c. A lot of it might be wrong but from a small tutorial this is what i figured out.

```
NSString *word = self.translateTextField.text;

NSArray *vowels;
vowels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"b",@"c",@"d",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"v",@"q",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z", nil];

NSArray *compArray = [word componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
int i;

for (i = 0; self.translateTextField.text != '\0'; i++){
    //NSLog (@"Element %i = %@", i, [vowels objectAtIndex: i]);
    if([compArray objectAtIndex:i] == [vowels objectAtIndex:i]){
        self.translationTextField.text = ;
    }
    else
        self.translationTextField.text = ;

}
```

Basically if you write home into the `translateTextField` and hit the `translatePressed` button I want it to output hop o mop e in the `translationTextField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to a solution. I have modified your code a bit and made it into a function. The input parameter is your word, but it will work on any string. I have also changed your letter array into a string (consonants, not vowels, right?). You can certainly use separate strings also, then you just modify the if statement slightly.

The core of the method extracts a single letter at a time by using the `NSString` method `substringWithRange:`, then tests if the `consonants` string contains this letter. It may seems backwards, and in fact, you can reverse it, so that you loop through the `consonants` string and test if each of them are present in the `word` string instead. It doesn't matter much which way you do it.

I have also added a function `goButtonPressed:` that show you how to use the `translate:` function. This can be connected from your storyboard button, assuming you have an `UILabel` for output called `resultLabel` and your input is located in an `UITextField` called `inputField`.

Finally, please note the `stringWithFormat:` that works similar to `printf()`. However, I use `%C` (*capital* C) to output Unicode characters. While lowercase `%c` will work for US ASCII, it will fail on other characters.

```
- (NSString *)translate:(NSString *)word {
    NSString *consonats = @"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwqxyz";

    NSString *result = @"";
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if ([consonats containsString:[word substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]])
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%Cop ", result, [word characterAtIndex:i]];
        else
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%C ", result, [word characterAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return result;
}

- (IBAction)goButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    _resultLabel.text = [self translate:_inputField.text];
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, and yea consonants not vowels. It was named vowels cause at first i was gonna make an array of vowels but ended up as consonants and just forgot to change it and left it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, notable points:

- It uses `enumerateSubstringsInRange` with the option `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` to process the text a character a time. Using this method ensures that Unicode is processed properly, e.g. emojis and other composed sequences are treated correctly as single "characters". This method also used a *block*, an (Objective-)C inline function to process each individual "character".
- The final text is built up in a mutable string, `translated`, enabling it to be efficiently accumulated.
- Your original array of strings is retained, instead of looping through it membership is tested using `conainsObject:`

The fragment could do with improving, e.g. it adds one too many spaces, but gives the general idea:

```
 NSString *word = @"home";

 NSArray *constants = @[@"b", @"c", @"d", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"j",
                        @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"p", @"q", @"r",
                        @"s", @"t", @"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", @"z"];

 NSMutableString *translated = [NSMutableString new]; // mutable string to build up result in

 [word enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, word.length)
                          options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences // enumerate by "character"
                       usingBlock:^(NSString *nextChar, NSRange ignoreOne, NSRange ignoreTwo, BOOL *ignoreThree)
                       {
                           [translated appendString:nextChar]; // add the character
                           if ([constants containsObject:nextChar]) [translated appendString:@"op"]; // append "op" if a consonant
                           [translated appendString:@" "];  // append space (note that overall one too many is appended by this sample)
                       }];

 NSLog(@"%@", translated);
```

HTH